# Calculate the motion of a simple object in 3d

Tags: python, opencv

I'm a beginner in python and raspberry pi and for a school project which is due this month, we're using a raspberry pi 3 and a camera module (fixed) and the idea is when u move something in the camera frame the program gives an output of where this object is according to the camera (in 3D) and the distance this object has traveled, it  would be something like ( x=2.98m, y=5.56m, z=3.87m, distance=0.677m ) and all of this using optical flow and python. Is it possible to make this and if not Is there something close or similar to this. Please guys i need help I'm really stuck here and thank you in advance.

Comment: doesn't really have anything to do specifically with raspberry pi

Comment: Of course it is possible.  But we are not here to write your project for you.

Comment: Is this how you are taught to create a system at Abou Bakr Belkaïd? Maybe your instructor will read this and decide to help you.

Comment: Of course not sir, but i just need some guidelines on where to begin or search because it's not really my specialty.

Comment: I also thought that it's not a raspberry pi application but the instructor specified that we use it

Comment: Well if you had a question specific to troubleshooting an issue with the raspberry pi handling the camera feed/creating mysterious errors that could be related to the operating system or hardware this would be the place to ask. The hardest part is probably going to be the programming, but you will have to google optical flow and python related help or use the programming related Stack Overflow site. raspberrypi.stackexchange really is specific to just Rpi stuff... Good luck.

Comment: This is not a Raspberry Pi specific question. The solution does not depend on the computer it is running on. I would suggest that you ask on https://stackoverflow.com/ instead.